# animationControllerForOperation isn't called on iOS 10

Tags: ios

My application is using custom transition animation for push & pop animations (including interactive transition). Everything worked fine until iOS 10.

Now `animationControllerForOperation` is called on `pushViewControllerAnimated:` & `popViewControllerAnimated:` but not on interactive pop (it worked fine on previous iOS versions).

`gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:` is still called but UINavigationControllerDelegate isn't.

Could you help me to fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?